# Create side artifact from directory

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am currently writing a Maven plugin that creates some files in a subdirectory of target. My wish is to zip these files and deploy them as side artifact.

More precisely:

Say I have created some files in `target/someplugin`. Then I want to zip these files and attach them to the build, so that the zip is installed/deployed with classifier `someplugin`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not using maven-assembly-plugin ?

Comment: Good question. I want to write a plugin that one can (easily) add in a parent pom, and for the assembly plugin, I did not understand how I can configure this in the parent pom, including the assembly descriptor. Less important: I would mean to split the logic between my plugin (creating some files in a directory) and the assembly plugin (zipping those files and attaching them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following (may not be perfect):

First I injected the MavenProjectHelper

```
@Component
private MavenProjectHelper projectHelper;
```

Then I added the zt-zip library

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
  <artifactId>zt-zip</artifactId>
  <version>1.13</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Now I can do something like

```
ZipUtil.pack(someplugindir, somepluginzip);
projectHelper.attachArtifact(project, "zip", "someplugin", somepluginzip);
```

and everything looks fine.